# Update Error on my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am getting this error while my update never completed fully.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring because the mentioned PPA may not be available now. So, you need to remove it from the `sources.list` so that `apt` will ignore it.

From a terminal open the file (using `sudo`) `/etc/apt/sources.list` and find the line containing the mentioned PPA. Just put a `#` in front of the line to comment out the line and the save the file.

Now run `sudo apt-get update` and everything will be Ok.

Comment: I didn't see any PPA which is mentioned in that error